# Reason for Android onscreen keyboard not disappearing on outside touch event

Tags: android

Some UX expert at my job noted that the Android onscreen keyboard should disappear once the user taps any UI component but the focused EditText (or the keyboard itself of course).
Apparently Stackoverflow has multiple people asking for technical solutions to this behavior (e.g.: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4165414/how-to-hide-soft-keyboard-on-android-after-clicking-outside-edittext). Of course it's always possible to collapse the keyboard via the system back button.

So I was wondering whether this was by design and workarounds should not be applied at all, or this can even be considered some kind of bug?

Answer (score 3):

Seems like this is the intended design and workarounds would not be recommended IMO.
http://developer.android.com/training/keyboard-input/visibility.html

excerpt:

> Note: Once the input method is visible, you should not programmatically hide it. The system hides the input method when the user finishes the task in the text field or the user can hide it with a system control (such as with the Back button).

Seems like any workaround is a hack. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27216586/android-keyboard-is-not-hiding-on-touch-outside